# VLOOKUP troubles in Excel

Tags: excel, vlookup

I have a list of contacts. There are people, and companies, both in the same spreadsheet.

I need to copy a company's address (from column F) in to a person's address (also column F), based on a match. That is, E2 is my source cell, and the E column is what I need to match. When a match is made, the formula should copy F3 in to F2.

In plain English, I need to company company address values in to person address values. I've fiddled with VLOOKUP but can't get it to cooperate.

See this example: http://versastudio.com/misc/excel_vlookup.png

Comment: (1) There are many examples of `VLOOKUP` questions here already (2) This is more a question for Super User than programming for StackOverlow. (3) See Patrick Matthews [Six-Reasons-Why-Your-VLOOKUP-or-HLOOKUP-Formula-Does-Not-Work](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Software/Office_Productivity/Office_Suites/MS_Office/Excel/A_2637-Six-Reasons-Why-Your-VLOOKUP-or-HLOOKUP-Formula-Does-Not-Work.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the company address against person, by using `Match` and `Index` Formula in Array Formula.

[image]

Select Cell Range `G2:G5` and Then in First Cell (`G2`) Place formula

`=IF(A2:A5="Person", INDEX(F2:F5,MATCH(E2:E5,C2:C5,0),1),F2:F5)`

and press `Ctrl + Shift + Enter`.

Might be, It help you.

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful. I'm not sure how to apply it to a larger list. Do I need absolute values like $F$5, etc.?

Comment: no need of absolute cell reference. It will work for larger list also.